# Android virtual device not starting up

Tags: android, eclipse, android-virtual-device

I am new to android development. I am trying to print hello world in android application.. I have written a code for it and i have created android virtual device for it. I have started android virtual device and waiting for emulator. I am waiting since last hour. i am not able to run this application.
I am using windows 8 operating system and eclipse.
Please help.
[android emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QsiY5.png)

Comment: are you getting any errors or messages in console???

Comment: Pc Configuration ? 
I would suggest you to use GenyMotion. It's Faster and Better!

Comment: Try lowering the amount of RAM the device is using below 768 MB. Windows won't start the emulator (in my experience) if the RAM it's trying to use is greater than that amount.

Comment: lal: i am tying to run test project which by default provided by android. but i am not able to run this project.

Comment: ishan: i5 processor, os: window8, ram: 4gb, 64 bit os

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use [Intel x86](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/12/android-boost-up-the-android-emulator-speed-up-to-400-on-intel-based-architecture.html) emulator